# Why would recursion cause discontinuities in processing time?

Tags: java, recursion, optimization

I'm in the process of optimizing my Strassen-Winograd algorithm for matrix multiplication in Java. I read on Wikipedia for the Strassen Algorithm that "if the matrices are sufficiently non-square it will be worthwhile reducing the initial operation to more square products," so I measured the calculation times for various matrix aspect ratios to find what I deemed too 'unsquare', based on the processing time required. However, while collecting data, it became clear that the formula for times was non-continuous. Aspect ratios above ~1.28 caused the algorithm's compute time to increase by a factor of about 10, as shown in the following image:
[image: 3d pyplot graph of aspect ratios versus compute time]

The multiplication was done with matrices of sizes `[A X B] * [B X C]`, where `B` is constant during the test, **Aspect Ratio 1** is `A/B`, and **Aspect Ratio 2** is `C/B`, where A and C vary.
I expected this discontinuity to shift when changing `B`, but at values 50, 100, and 200, the break in the surface remained in the same place.
Using a custom timer that works in recursive functions, I found that the only slowdown when crossing this aspect ratio threshold was the recursive parts of my function. They look like so:

```
Manix u, v, w;
// u = (A[2] - A[0]) X (B[1] - B[3])
u = A[2].sub(A[0], numberType).fastDot(B[1].sub(B[3], numberType), numberType);
// v = (A[2] + A[3]) X (B[1] - B[0])
v = A[2].add(A[3], numberType).fastDot(B[1].sub(B[0], numberType), numberType);
// w = A[0] X B[0] + (A[2] + A[3] - A[0]) X (B[0] + B[3] - B[1])
w = ABNaught.add(A[2].add(A[3].sub(A[0], numberType), numberType).fastDot(B[0].add(B[3], numberType).sub(B[1], numberType), numberType), numberType);


/* Strassen-Winograd:
 * 
 * |         A[0] X B[0] + A[1] X B[2]              v + w + (A[0] + A[1] - A[2] - A[3]) X B[3] |
 * |                                                                                           |
 * | u + w + A[3] X (B[1] + B[2] - B[0] - B[3])                      u + v + w                 |
 * 
 * Note that A[0] X B[0] is used here and in w, meaning we only have to calculate 7 multiplications instead of 8
*/

Manix[] productLayer = { 
        ABNaught.add(A[1].fastDot(B[2], numberType), numberType), 
        v.add(w, numberType).add(A[0].add(A[1], numberType).sub(A[2], numberType).sub(A[3], numberType).fastDot(B[3], numberType), numberType),
        u.add(w, numberType).add(A[3].fastDot(B[1].add(B[2], numberType).sub(B[0], numberType).sub(B[3], numberType), numberType), numberType), 
        u.add(v, numberType).add(w, numberType)
};
```

Tests were completed on the `add` and `sub` functions used in this section of code, and no abnormalities were found. The only functions left in the offending section are the `fastDot` recursive calls.
My expectation going into this data collection was to see a smooth surface, not a discontinuous one. My only explanation is that this has to do with Java's overhead for function calls, but nothing concrete. Would someone with more knowledge about Java's compiler like to take a crack at explaining this phenomenon?

Comment: How are you measuring compute time? Have you seen [the microbenchmarking tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/513259#513259)?

Comment: The threshold of ~1.28 refers to which value of B?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina The break in continuity happens at both `A/B=1.8` and `C/B=1.8`. As visualized in the graph, this happens predictably on both axes.

Comment: @k314159 I have never seen these microbenchmarking tips! A lot of them look useful. I’ll get back to you when I’ve covered the rules that have not yet been implemented.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the discontinuities may be caused by the garbage collector kicking in at certain points.

Comment: @k314159 I've covered most of the microbenchmarking rules that you suggested, and the issue was, indeed, with the garbage collector! At various `B` values, the garbage collector begins working approximately 7 times as hard at the 1.28 aspect ratio line. The question remains — why does this happen at this specific aspect ratio, even when the matrices (in these specific tests) vary in size by almost 100,000 elements?

Comment: You are focusing on the aspect ratio because you are tracking the aspect ratio, and not vice versa. This is a common bias. Probably if you track A*B and C*B you obtain the same pattern on a different scale, and I suppose that multiplication (or a similar one) is performed internally, that hits some memory threshold and the GC is executed. Thus the pattern is explained